# Load shared libraries from lib directory in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, ros2

I have downloaded a ROS2 demo from the [examples repository](https://github.com/ros2/examples).

Specifically, I have used [minimal_subscriber](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclcpp/minimal_subscriber) and [minimal_publisher](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclcpp/minimal_publisher).

I have ROS2 installed in `/opt/ros2` and when I build these two examples with `colcon build`, it generates an `install/` directory with `lib/`, `shared/` and the other usual directory structure.

I can execute and run these demos perfectly fine with my current setup in my machine, but these executables link to libraries present in `/opt/ros2`, so when I want to execute them in another machine without ROS2 installed or I move my ROS2 installation in my machine, the executables cannot find the shared objects.

I've added a really simple script that adds all dependencies to `install/lib` when building but the executables don't seem to care, they aren't looking for shared libraries in the generated `lib` directory, they keep trying to search in `/opt/ros2`.

I believe this is something I should solve in CMake and it's not ROS2 specific, so, is there any way I can tell my generated executables to search in a diferent directory? (`../lib` or `./lib` in my case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building them yourself (assumed since you mention CMake), you can set the RPATH in CMake ([docs here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling)). Specifically set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` something like:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
```

If you can't rebuild them, you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your environment to where the libraries are located, or you can patch the executables themselves with an updated RPATH by using [patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html).

In order to get a relative RPATH rather than an absolute RPATH, use the `$ORIGIN` variable in your rpath spec. See "[Recommendations](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling#recommendations)" the the link above for more details.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. It solves the /opt/ros2 dependency but creates another. `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` is a full path, so when moving my executables and libraries to another machine, I have to save them in the same path or it won't work, because it is searching for the same `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib` path and not a relative path

Comment: I added an update about getting relative paths using `$ORIGIN`.

Comment: It worked! In my particular case I had to use `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib")` because I launch from `install/bin/` and the libraries are in `install/lib/`. I now have the problem that some libraries are found while others are not, even though all are inside `lib/`, but that's another completely different problem. Thanks for you help :)